# How do I bind a macro to a key in Word 2007 without recording a new macro?

Tags: vba, ms-word, key-bindings

As the title so eloquently put it, I need to know how (or if it's even possible) to bind a macro to a key in Microsoft Word 2007 without recording a new macro each time.

I find myself writing new macros directly in code and then not being able to bind them to a key.  Or I might just want to rebind a macro to another key.

Comment: The question in the title actually asks how to do it from the GUI (not programmatically), for that it's (depends on the word version but) usually [file → options →  customize ribbons → keyboard shortcut → macros category] -- in some other versions see [the answer below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3663081/5267751).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Look at the `KeysBoundTo` collection - see [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb211993.aspx), the `BuildKeyCode` method - see [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb214070.aspx) and the list of `wdKey` constants [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb213870.aspx)

Answer (score 2):

As suggested, look up Word's `KeyBindings` object in the help file.

Additionally, if your macro must work with international keyboards, this is a very good read:

- [Do-It-Yourself IntelliSense](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa155749(office.10).aspx) (**The KeyBindings Mess** section)

Answer (score 2):

Here is an answer from Microsoft: http://office.microsoft.com/video.aspx?assetid=ES010336334&vwidth=884&vheight=540&CTT=11&Origin=

Essentially,

1. Click the Office Button.

2. Select Word Options (near the bottom next to Exit Word).

3. Select Customize.

4a. If you want to add the macro to a button, select "Macros" from the dropdown under "Choose commands from:".

4b. If you want to add a keybind, click Customize (at the bottom towards the left, next to "Keyboard shortcuts:".  Here is the same window as when you create a new macro.  Just be sure to click "Assign" after picking the keystroke.

Answer (score 1):

The best solution I've come up with has been to record a new empty macro to the key I want (say, Ctrl+Num . [the Del key on the numpad]) and name the macro ctrl_num_dot.  Then I can call any macro from the ctrl_num_dot subroutine.